# SQL distinct User IDs by User Type stability over time

Tags: mysql, sql

Table structure includes:

```
User_ID , User_Type , Time_Period (integer)
---------------------------------
12345   ,      1     ,    201501
12346   ,      1     ,    201501
12347   ,      2     ,    201501
12345   ,      1     ,    201502
12346   ,      2     ,    201502
```

Over time,

- Unique User_IDs can leave User_Type completely
- New User_IDs can be added in any Time_Period
- User_IDs can migrate to other User_Types in each Time_Period.

I need to write code to understand the stability of users in a user type over 12 periods, eg, 70% of distinct User_IDs stayed in User_Type 1 over periods 201501 to 201512

Output should be a list by User_Type of a count of distinct User_IDs who remained in the same User_Type over 12 time periods, and a second column of the total number of distinct User_IDs in the same time period

```
User_Type , Count Distinct Same User_IDs , Count Distinct Total User_IDs
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1         ,              146,023         ,       201,501
2         ,              46,124          ,       147,234
3         ,              27,500          ,       87,954
```

This is my first time posting, so please let me know if you need more detail and thanks in advance

EDIT - User_ID can appear in the table multiple times, due to each time period, but only once per period.

Comment: Edit your question and provide the desired results you want to achieve.  What is the data type of `Time_Period`?  Is there one row for each user for each month?

Answer (score 0):

If each user is present in each month and you want to find the proportion of users that are present in all 12 months and remain "1", then one method is:

```
select avg(minut = 1 and maxut = 1)
from (select user_id, min(user_type) as minut, max(user_type) as maxut
      from t
      where left(time_period, 4) = '2015'
      group by user_id
      having count(*) = 12 
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. To clarify, although each User_ID CAN have one row per period as a record in the table they MAY NOT. If they didn't interact in a period, the User_ID is not recorded for that period on the table.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you the behavior of users.
Each user is counted once in one of the rows.
A row describes the phases of a users - its existent and its user_type in each month.
It be easier to understand this report if you'll increase you data sample.

```
select      count(*)    as users
           ,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,`10`,`11`,`12`

from       (select      user_id

                       ,min(case when time_period = 201501 then user_type end) as `1`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201502 then user_type end) as `2`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201503 then user_type end) as `3`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201504 then user_type end) as `4`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201505 then user_type end) as `5`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201506 then user_type end) as `6`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201507 then user_type end) as `7`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201508 then user_type end) as `8`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201509 then user_type end) as `9`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201510 then user_type end) as `10`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201511 then user_type end) as `11`
                       ,min(case when time_period = 201512 then user_type end) as `12`

            from        mytable

            group by    user_id
            ) t

group by    `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,`10`,`11`,`12`          

order by    users desc
```

---

```
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| users | 1 | 2      | 3      | 4      | 5      | 6      | 7      | 8      | 9      | 10     | 11     | 12     |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1     | 1 | 2      | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1     | 2 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1     | 1 | 1      | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
+-------+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, this is pretty much there, it appears its a raw count versus needing to understand it is the same User_ID counted in each period any idea how to add this?

Comment: Each user is counted once and the row he is counted in describes its movement through the months whether is is a type change or dis/appearing. If you have a row in this reports with users = 12615 it means 12,615 users had the exact same behaviour which is described it the rest of the columns

Comment: Hi, was it helpful for you?